# Djongo + Django + MongoDB not support chainning filter

Tags: python, django, mongodb, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have two model: **Content** and **Tag** that have **ManyToMany** realationship

```
Content(models.Model):
    tags  = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, 
                                   null=False, 
                                   blank=False,
                                   related_name="tags")

Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
```

Notice that I'm using **MongoDB** and **djongo** connector to work with my db.
Now I want to filter "All of content that have n specific tags", example: all of the content that have tags = ["Movie", "News", "Science"], suppose id of them is: 1, 2, 3 corresponding.
I have used chaining filter.
`content.objects.filter(tags=1).filter(tags=2).filter(tags=3)`
but it return not found.
Yep, of course contents that have id = [1, 2, 3] are available in my database.
**But when I migrate to MySQL and try again, it work and return a queryset that I expected.**